# Edgejs with node application not running on Mac computer

Tags: .net, node.js, npm, .net-4.5, edgejs

I have node application using Edgejs module to run some .net dll. My application is running on Windows machine but when run same application on Mac computer I get following error:

> CoreClrEmbed`enter code here`ding::Initialize - Could not resolve
>   CoreCLR path.  For more details, enable tracing by setting
>   COREHOST_TRACE environment variable to 1 module.js:664

```
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^
```

> Error: This is not a published, standalone application and we are 
>       unable to locate the .NET Core SDK.  Please make sure that it is 
>       installed; see http://microsoft.com/net/core for more de
>           at Object.node_modules/edge-js/lib/edge.js:54:8)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that your Mac is configured correctly as per https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/tree/master#scripting-clr-from-nodejs?

Comment: I tried all possible option given in above link but still i am getting error.
CoreClrEmbedding::Initialize - Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070057
/Users/code/node_modules/edge-js/lib/edge.js:179
    return edge.initializeClrFunc(options);
                ^

TypeError: edge.initializeClrFunc is not a function

Comment: A quick search of your issue comes up with some people on github who appear to have fixed it, it seems like your environment isn't correctly configured https://github.com/agracio/electron-edge-js-quick-start/issues/5